# How to get the index lenth of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a python code like

```
            for i in re.finditer('something(.+?)"', html):
```

I am now trying to find out how many times its going to loop before going to that loop..in other words the length of array i.
Could anyone give me an alternative but similar code with with I get length of the loop.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need to know the length beforehand?

Comment: I'd like to show a progress of the activity with percentage..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = list(re.finditer('something(.+?)"', html))

if len(x)
     ....

for i in x:
     ....
```

`findall` is not an adequate replacement since it returns strings, not match objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `re.finditer` because it returns an **iterator** which doesn't know when it's finished until it does (since it finds the next match on each iteration) ..., you'll have to use `re.findall`.

```
matches = re.findall('something(.+?)"', html)
num_loops = len(matches)
```

or use @thg435's approach if you do in fact need the match objects.

Comment: How do I implement re.findall as well as get the index number?

Comment: @Abul Hasnat you just use `len(..)` on the list. If you want the index number for each match then do `for i, m in enumerate(re.findall(...))`

Answer (score 1):

`finditer` returns the results as it finds them. There is no way `finditer` can tell you how many times you will loop in advance.

You need to use something else. Either `re.findall` or possibly `re.search` to get the length